# Does "Salary After Attending" variable include all attendees or only those who graduate?

Tags: collegescorecard

I'd like to chart some institutions' typical total debt variable against the salary after attending variable.  I know the typical total debt variable is only for students who complete, but what about the salary after attending variable?  The documentation report seems to suggest it includes all students, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Earnings cohorts include both graduates and non-graduates